# How to show a "are u sure YES OR NOT" dialog when user press a button?

Tags: android, dialog

first of all, i have to tell you that i have searched here and on google and i can't find a easy way to do it (im newbie on this), then i need your help please

i have this button, that removes a friend from the remote database:

```
removeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                con.deletePermission(settings.getString("login",""),bundle.getString("email"));
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.friendsuccessfullyremoved), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

i just want to show a simple "Are you sure? YES or NOT" dialog with two buttons (YES AND NOT) and when the user press YES, it have to be called this code:

```
con.deletePermission(settings.getString("login",""),bundle.getString("email"));
                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.friendsuccessfullyremoved), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

exist's a easy way to do it?

thanks

EDIT: i try to do it with this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html  but it doesn't works, nothing happens when i press the button, no dialog appear

my new code:

```
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();//get the intent & bundle passed by X
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        removeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*
                con.deletePermission(settings.getString("login",""),bundle.getString("email"));
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.friendsuccessfullyremoved), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                */
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure?")
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                con.deletePermission(settings.getString("login",""),bundle.getString("email"));
                                finish();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.friendsuccessfullyremoved), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }
                       })
                       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#create%28%29):

> Creates a AlertDialog with the
>   arguments supplied to this builder. It
>   does not show() the dialog. This
>   allows the user to do any extra
>   processing before displaying the
>   dialog. Use show() if you don't have
>   any other processing to do and want
>   this to be created and displayed.

That means, you need to call `show()`.

Comment: it doesn't works, i dont know why, im editing first post with mi code, please check it and tell me why doesnt works

Answer (score 2):

yeah it's missing

```
 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
 alert.show();
```

This is assuming you want to show the alert dialogue as soon as the button has been pressed.